# How to have a turn by turn management in C?

Tags: c

I want to make a game; say there are 50 turns and up to 4 players.
How should the code manage the turn by turn?

For 2 player I think it is that:

```
    if (nbr_gamers == 2)
    {
         if ((turn % 2) == 0)
              player = 1;
         else
              player = 0;
    }
```

where the turn is the position of turn.
Is that about right?

Comment: Sorry, we are no consulting site, your question is too broad or too opinion based. Just that: There is a datatype which can store objects of the same type and access them by an index...

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
player = turn % nbr_gamers;
```

Comment: It's interesting that when `turn == 0`, the code in the question returns `player == 1` whereas this returns `player == 0`.  However, this is probably the better system to use; it is the orthodox one, at any rate.